# React - Stacking flex items on an overflow div in iOS Safari

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, overflow

I am having a problem with stacking some cards on the mobile version of an application I'm developing that is using a react conversation component. On the desktop version and in inspect mode, the cards stack perfectly with a 15px space between them but when I fire it up on iPhone, I get the result you can see in the 3rd picture. I cannot find where this bug comes from and any help or similar issues stories are very welcome.

```
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        style={{
          overflowY: 'auto',
          WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
        }}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        {...conversationProps}
      >
        {messages.map((item, index) => (
          <Box
            ref={ref}
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="row"
            justifyContent={
              item.user.username === username ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start'
            }
            marginBottom={Spaces.component}
          >
              <ApplicationMessage
                key={index}
                isFromMe={item.user.username === username ? true : false}
                profilePicture={item.user.profile_picture}
                username={item.user.username}
                timestamp={item.timestamp}
                message={item.data.message}
                timestampLanguage={timestampLanguage}
                containerProps={{ flexShrink: 0 }}
              />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

On desktop:

[image: Desktop Chrome]

On responsive console (chrome):

[image: Responsive Chrome]

On Safari:

[image: iOS Safari]

Thank you,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, I just removed `flex` property to the scrollable (overflow) div.

It renders something like that in my code :

```
      <Box
        overflowY="auto"
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        {...conversationProps}
      >
        {messages.map((item, index) => (
          <Box
            ref={ref}
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="row"
            justifyContent={
              item.user.username === username ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start'
            }
            marginBottom={Spaces.component}
          >
              <ApplicationMessage
                key={index}
                isFromMe={item.user.username === username ? true : false}
                profilePicture={item.user.profile_picture}
                username={item.user.username}
                timestamp={item.timestamp}
                message={item.data.message}
                timestampLanguage={timestampLanguage}
                containerProps={{ flexShrink: 0 }}
              />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
```